# Debugging impossible when gtk dropdown active

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, gtk

I have a window, with several Gtk-2.0 widgets. One of them is a GtkEntry, with the corresponding GtkCompletion connected.

I need to debug the code called when a selection ('match' event) is made in the dropdown shown by the GtkCompletion. So I set a breakpoint, activate the selection, and the entire desktop hangs. The only form I found to get out is Ctl-Alt-Backspace, and delete the gdb instance.

When this happens, the entire windows manager remains as if the dropdown is still active - only responds to Ctl-Alt functions, like Ctl-Alt-F2.

I tried the --sync commandline option, but that didn't make any difference. Though there seem to be some (rather complicated) solutions such as running a nested Window server, or debug remotely, I can't imagine there isn't a more elegant solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time.

You need to grab another laptop, or a console on another server, and ssh into your primary desktop/laptop. Start your GTK application on your main desktop/laptop, then attach gdb to it from your connection from your other laptop/machine.

Then, you will run your gtk application on your main screen, and debug it from a separate connection, without interfering with your primary display.

EDIT: I see that you already considered remote debugging, but in my experience it's really not that difficult. I just have another laptop on my desk, next to me, to debug my X applications.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I went through tens of sites, both before and after I posted the question, couldn't really find clear indications on _how_ to do it exactly. But maybe I was looking too specifically for the dropdown issue and should have looked around with more general terms. Still, I thought this problem would be common enough for there to be a more elegant solution. I'm not that experienced a programmer... Thanks for replying!